# custom-symbolic icons for places in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, icons, gvfs

I know it is possible to set custom-icons for folders with using

```
gvfs-set-attribute /home/folder metadata::custom-icon-name folder-whatever
```

but nautilus uses symbolic icons `standard::symbolic-icon`(?) in the sidebar-tree.

Is it possible to set custom symbolic icons as well using `gvfs-set-attribute` (or any other method)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, as it results in this error:

```
 Error setting attribute: Setting attribute standard::symbolic-icon not supported
```

You can list the writeable attributes of a folder/file (e.g. `$HOME`, the users's home directory) by running:

```
 gvfs-info -w $HOME
```

for this I get:

```
Settable attributes:
 standard::symlink-target (bytestring)
 time::access (uint64, Keep with file when moved)
 time::access-usec (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
 time::modified (uint64, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 time::modified-usec (uint32, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::gid (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::mode (uint32, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 unix::uid (uint32, Keep with file when moved)
Writable attribute namespaces:
 metadata (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 xattr (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)
 xattr-sys (string, Keep with file when moved)
```

For the standard folder icon, this is set by `metadata::custom-icon` (or whatever), which comes under the `metadata` name-space. Any other attributes that aren't listed are not writeable - including `standard::symbolic-icon`. ***N.B.*** creating `metadata::symbolic-icon` or similar and restarting nautilus seems to have no effect either

**Sources/More info**

- [`man gvfs-info`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/gvfs-info.1.html)
- [GFileAttribute](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/gio-GFileAttribute.html) <sub>*may be helpful - linked from man page*</sub>

Comment: That's a shame; Strangely enough: my /home/user/Dropbox folder (the one that is created during installation) does have the attribute `metadata:symbolic-icon` preconfigured; but then, no symbolic icon is shown for it

Comment: @wa4557 - I just tested that (and `metadata::custom-symbolic-icon`) to see if there is a `metadata` setting for symbolic icon that overrides the the `standard` one. It does not seem work (on Gnome/Nautilus 3.8) though - it may work on other setups. This is probably included by Dropbox by default.